# Loading bar scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, loading, progress

I have 2 scenes in my Unity Project. The first one is a loading scene which consist of a simple text and a slide bar. And the second scene is a random generator of 'terrain'(3 differents cubes of size 1x1x1).

The time it gets to load the second scene is about 15 seconds, but when I use the method progress from AsyncOperation, I only get the values 0 or 0.9.

This is my script for the loading bar:

```
IEnumerator LoadingScreen(int level)
{
    button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    loadingScreenObj.SetActive(true);

    AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(level);
    async.allowSceneActivation = false;
    Debug.Log(async.progress);

    while(!async.isDone){
        slider.value = async.progress;
        Debug.Log(slider.value);
        if (async.progress >= 0.9f){
            slider.value = 1f;
            async.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And the script for the terrain generator is:

```
public class SpawnInitialFloor : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject [] prefabs;
private GameObject floor;
List<Vector2> list = new List<Vector2>();
private float y = 0;
private float yWater = -0.1f;
public int maxIterations = 50;
private int max = 1;
private int min = -1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start (){
    setSpawn(); 
}

private void setSpawn()
{
    int r;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; ++i){
        for (int xIt = min; xIt <= max; ++xIt){
            for (int zIt = min; zIt <= max; ++zIt){
                if (!list.Contains(new Vector2(xIt, zIt))){
                    r = Random.Range(0, 3);
                    if (r == 1)
                        floor = Instantiate(prefabs[r], new Vector3(xIt, yWater, zIt), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    else
                        floor = Instantiate(prefabs[r], new Vector3(xIt, y, zIt), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

                    list.Add(new Vector2(xIt, zIt));
                }
            }
        }
        max += 1;
        min -= 1;
    }
}
}
```

The loading bar always looks like this for about the 15 seconds of the other scene loading: [Loading Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQFLd.png)

And before and after the complete load of the second scene:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcpye.png) - [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np1Ow.png)

I wanted to know if I have to change something in the SpawnInitialFloor script or use other thing instead of the progress method of AsyncOperation.

Comment: Just curious about your slider value.  Can you verify that when it is a 0 value it's always empty.  I say this because 0.1..0.8, etc may be getting truncated down to 0 or up to 1, who knows.  You may have a rounding issue on your slider.

Comment: The slide changes perfect with the values 0.1...0.8, but the problem is that the async.progress always give the values:
0 before enter the loop(1 time shown in the console). And 0.9 inside de loop(2 times shown in the console).

Comment: I cannot comment on the second scene but for the first scene, it is working properly. Most of the times, in the editor, the progress jump but when you actually build it, it will take time and you will see the progress bar loading.